# tkz-euclide: \tkzDrawCircle[R] not working

Tags: tkz-euclide

`\tkzDrawArc[R,arc](B,1.1*\dBD)(20,83)` works well. But `\tkzDrawCircle[R]` is not working...

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,6){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(8,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)


\tkzDrawSegment[thick](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](A,C)

\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzInterLC(A,C)(M,C) \tkzGetPoints{D}{E} \tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](B,D)
\tkzCalcLength[cm](B,D) \tkzGetLength{dBD}
\tkzDrawArc[R,arc](B,1.1*\dBD)(20,83)
\tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.1*\dBD)
%\tkzInterLC[R](A,C)(B,1.1*\dBD) \tkzGetPoints{D_1}{D_2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible ´\tkzDrawSegments[thick](A,B B,C C,A)´ or ´\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)’ . In the documentation you can find other possibilities to transform pt in cm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The macro `\tkzGetLength` returns the length expressed in `pt`, if you use `cm`, you must convert this measurement to cm when calling it.

`\tkzDrawCircle[R](A,\dBD cm)` 
instead of `\tkzDrawCircle[R](A,\dBD)`

In addition, calculations are prohibited during the passage of parameters to allow you to choose the calculation engine (see p 57 of manual):

- `pgf` with `\pgfsetmacro`
- `fp` with `\fpeval`

  ```
  \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  \usetkzobj{all}
  \definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
  \pagecolor{fondpaille}
  \color{Maroon} 

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B} 
  \tkzDefPoint(0,6){A} 
  \tkzDefPoint(8,0){C}
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](B,C)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)


  \tkzDrawSegment[thick](A,B)
  \tkzDrawSegment[thick](C,B)
  \tkzDrawSegment[thick](A,C)

  \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{M}
  \tkzInterLC(A,C)(M,C) \tkzGetPoints{D}{E} \tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
  \tkzDrawSegment[thick](B,D)
  \tkzCalcLength[cm](B,D) \tkzGetLength{dBD}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tkzLen}{1.1*\dBD}
  \tkzDrawArc[R,arc](B, \tkzLen cm)(20,83)
  \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,\dBD cm)
  \tkzInterLC[R](A,C)(B, \tkzLen cm ) \tkzGetPoints{D_1}{D_2}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

output

[image: tkz-euclide]

Comment: You are right. We have the possibility to use fp or pgf and perhaps lua if can work !